# Link in Ad Paragraph hides its attributes

Tags: go, web-scraping, go-colly

I am currently creating a webscraper and playing around the blog techcrunch.
While trying to retrieve the data from a specific blogpost I encounter a few ads, that I want to filter out.
[image: Filter for ads]
I am trying to differentiate between links inside of the article and links in the ads to solve the problem.
Unfortunately the classname of the ad-link is not retrieved inside the child attributes, while the content-link contains its classname.
[image: Ad-Link]
[image: Content-Link]

I tried to extract the classname of the ad-link, but they were the only classnames not beeing retrieved.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by checking the element.DOM.Parent() element